# R Create package using devtools and roxygen library issue

Tags: r, version, devtools

I recently combined many of my R functions into my first package!  However, I'm running into a couple issues that I'm not sure how to resolve. I have run check() and document() seemingly successfully (no errors and the only warning is related to my "license" because I did not add a license statement [is this safe to just remove until I know what license I need?]).

After document() I can use my package in a script during the same session.  However, if I start a new session and install.package(package), I get the following error and cannot library(package):

"package not available for version"

If I again document(PackageName), then I can again use it without issue.  Presently the package is just stored on my hard drive, but once I have this issue resolved I will be sharing it with my team.

Below is my DESCRIPTION file in case the issue has to do with that.

```
Package: PackageName
Title: Package Title
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: This is filled out
Maintainer: This is filled out.
Description: I have some description here. 
Depends: R (>= 3.1.0)
License: What license is it under?
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 7.1.0
Imports: dplyr,
  data.table,
  ggplot2,
  stringr,
  utils, 
  stats,
  scales
```

Thanks in advance for any help or advice! Also - in case this affects anything - I use RStudio.

Comment: You need to install your package.  I think `devtools` has a way to fake installation; I never use that, but apparently you have.  Don't do that, do a real install.  From the command line, run `R CMD INSTALL pkgdir`.  (`devtools` probably has a way to do that too.)

Comment: The version error actually occurs when I do "install.packages("PackageName")".  Sorry I did not make that clear.  I will edit my question to make that clear!

Comment: That command installs from CRAN.  If you want to do a local install, use `install.packages("path/to/PackageName", repos = NULL, type = "source")`.  RStudio does this with the `Build | Install and Restart...` menu item.

Comment: Thanks! I had the "path/to/PackageName", but not the repos = NULL, type = "source"